# Generalized Eigenvalue problem for degenerate matrices AND Jordan form

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I'm looking for a way to combine two eigenvalue decomposition methods implemented in Matlab. The first method implements the generalized eigenvalue problem, and can be used as follows:

```
[Gamma, Lambda] = eig(M1, M2);
```

If matrix M2 is not degenerate, this method returns the same answer as eig(M2^(-1) * M1), but I need to use this generalized form, because M2 may be degenerate.

I also have the problem that the returned matrix of eigenvectors is degenerate, so to get the eigenvalue decomposition, I need to use the Jordan form. If matrix M2 were not degenerate, I could use:

```
[Gamma, Lambda] = jordan(M2 \ M1)
```

But this does not work, because M2 is degenerate.

Is there any way to combine these two methods, so I could solve the problem of eigenvalue decomposition for the case where M2 and Gamma are both degenerate?

UPD: Minimal reproducible example:

```
M1 = [2 -1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 0]; M2 = [0 0 0; 0 2 -1; 0 1 0];
[Gamma, Lambda] = eig(M1, M2)
Gamma = 
     0 1 0
     0 0 0
    -1 0 1
Lambda = 
     0 0   0
     0 Inf 0
     0 0   0
```

In this example, I'm ok that some eigenvalues are infinite, but I need a non-degenerate Gamma.

Comment: I'd suggest you post a [mcve], you're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: Justin, thank you, I added an example.